# I want to change the background color of my navbar when scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

My navbar is in a main container which is including the first section page too. I made my navbar fixed and want its background change when scrolled but i dont know js. I'm giving you the html and css code please make script for that so i can attach it to the file.

.container {
background-image:radial-gradient(circle 920px at center,#286dec 0,#286dec 24%,#2767e7 32%,#244dd2 66%,#244dd2 91%);
box-shadow: 0 12px 21px #7889b6;
}

```
.header {
  height: 11vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 4;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  
  
}


.con3 a img {
  height: 2.22rem;
  color: white;
}

.logo h1 {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgb(255, 253, 253);
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgb(131, 128, 128);
}

.navbar {
  width: 37%;
}

.nav-items {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
}

.dropbtn {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 550;
}

.nav-items a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  font-weight: 550;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgb(0, 2, 148);
}

.nav-items li a:hover {
  font-size: 1.2rem;

}

ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li.active ul {
  display: block;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.dropbtn {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropbtn:hover {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 220px;
  min-height: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  padding: 13px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: show your html please

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    document.onscroll = function(){
     var nvbar = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar')[0];
     
     
     if(window.scrollY > 100)
     {
        nvbar.style.background = '#0094FF'
     }
     else
     {
        nvbar.style.background = '#4CFF00'
     }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: actually the header is main navbar,nav tag is for links.

Comment: So replace `navbar` with `header `